# Usar la api de gmail con java

Tags: java, gmail, google-api

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en spring que me permita usar la api de gmail para enviar y leer correos desde mi app. En mi pc local cuando uso la app por primera vez me redirige a la pagina de google y selecciono la cuenta con la que me quiero conectar, luego se descarga un archivo en mi pc y con eso ya me puedo conectar. El problema surge cuando subo mi app al servidor Ubuntu, este no tiene entorno gráfico sino modo consola, por lo tanto no puedo entrar a la pagina de google desde ahi y si intento usar el archivo descargado en mi pc al servidor no funciona.
Hay alguna forma de usar la api sin descargar ese archivo o alguna otra forma de poder descargar el archivo en ubuntu?

Comment: ¿No puedes instalar un entorno gráfico? Hasta donde yo sé no hay otra manera

Comment: El cliente tiene contratado un vps en amazon, y solo tiene habilitado el modo consola, no se si se pueda habilitar el entorno gráfico.